# Delete Message for everyone

Tags: android, applozic

Is delete message functionality for everyone in group chat exists and also delete functionality for sender to delete message from receiver's end in 1:1 chat in Applozic SDK. Are these delete for everyone functionality supported by Applozic chat sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Applozic chat SDK, We have a delete message for all in group chat only currently.

You will have to long-tap the sent message to see the menu with options and select Delete for all option you can check the below image.

[image]